# Override a generator method within a class

Tags: php, overriding, generator

I have a method within a class that yields a couple of values. When calling the `parent::generator_function()` the values are not yielded. How yield them

```
class Papa
{
    public function generator_function()
    {
        yield 1;
        yield 2;
        yield 3;
    }
}

class Child extends Papa
{
    public function generator_function()
    {
        parent::generator_function();
        yield 4;
    }

}

$child = new Child();
foreach ($child->generator_function() as $value) {
    echo "$value\n";
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply calling `parent::generator_function()` gives you a generator, which you're doing nothing with. Within a generator you can [delegate to another generator via `yield from`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php#control-structures.yield.from).

> In PHP 7, generator delegation allows you to yield values from another generator, Traversable object, or array by using the **yield from** keyword. The outer generator will then yield all values from the inner generator, object, or array until that is no longer valid, after which execution will continue in the outer generator.

E.g.:

```
class Child extends Papa
{
    public function generator_function()
    {
        yield from parent::generator_function();
        yield 4;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calling the generator in the parent class, but this is yielding the values to the caller - which is your method in the derived class.  So you would need to pass these values on to the calling method by yielding the return values, something like...

```
class Child extends Parent1
{
    public function generator_function()
    {
        foreach ( parent::generator_function() as $out )  {
            yield $out;
        }
//         parent::generator_function();
        yield 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: makes sense but looks weird to me thanks is this the only option?

Comment: May be a case of wait and see if any other answers come up.